# Some auto increment id has hide form mysql. How can i show these?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I cannot see some id form mysql. But when I query by php it show. What is the problem?

[image]

Here is missing id number 1632.

[image]

but When i query by php, it is showing.

Comment: One of the queries (or rendering of such) is filtering out the value and/or represents different data and/or otherwise does something special. Figure out why. In any case, an auto-increment column is *not* guaranteed to be dense and should not be used in a manner that assumes such.

Comment: Can we have your database structure, a sample data row and the PHP code you are currently using?

Comment: just sort your id column and check. or query your database directly (phpmyadmin etc.) like `select from table where id = 1632`

Comment: @Sujay why need code? I just want 1632 no. row in phpmyadmin. Where is it?